# Visual Studio Code Folder Naming Convention

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code under the main folder I accidently transposed the HTML acronym to HTLM. Does anyone know how I can change it to HTML? I've tried renaming it but it won't let me. Thanks. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wkr2B.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is the name of the folder. Make sure you close the folder first as it wont let you make changes unless all references to that folder are closed. In windows use File Explorer(Right click folder and rename). In Mac you can use Finder to rename.

You can also do it using terminal/command prompt. Open the location in them and type

```
mv HTLM HTML
```

Comment: Fixed. Thanks much!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for letting me know. Can you please mark this as answer if ur satisfied with this

Answer (score 1):

HTML appears to be the name of a folder. You can use file explorer on Windows, or similar program on Mac or Linux, to navigate to and rename the folder.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks much!

Comment: @MattPowers No problem! If my answer worked, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark. Thanks!